# authenticate not working in django with my custom user model

Tags: python, django

i have a custom user model and custom login page based on djamgo forms:

my forms.py is :

```
from django import forms


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    Username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'username-in',
        'placeholder': 'enter your username...'
    }))
    Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'password-in',
        'placeholder': 'enter your password...',
        'type': 'password'
    }))
```

in my custom user model i add some fields like this :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, User


class UserDetails(AbstractUser):
    SuperUser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    BranchManager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    FinanceManager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    BranchName = models.ForeignKey('stock.Branch', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

in my view.py for login :

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from users.forms import LoginForm


def LoginPage(request):
    forms = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['Username']
            password = request.POST['Password']
            x = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if x:
                login(request, x)
                return redirect('/stock')
    context = {'form': forms}
    return render(request, "users/login.html", context)


def UserRegister(request):
    return render(request, 'users/register.html')


def LogoutPage(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```

for checking data comes from form i use print() function to see what data will receive from form, username and password is what should be but when i print(x) that comes from this line -->  `

> x = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

` the result is None and if statement not working and user cannot login.
in stteing.py of project i add this line:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserDetails'
```

why django not authenticate the user and return None in authenticate()??

!!!EDIT FOR MORE Info:

i change my views.py to this to declare the users and obtain get data from db :

```
def LoginPage(request):
    forms = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            formusername = forms.cleaned_data['Username']
            formpassword = forms.cleaned_data['Password']
            x = UserDetails.objects.get(username=formusername)
            username = x.username
            password = x.password
            print(formusername)
            print(username)
            print(formpassword)
            print(password)
            x = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            print(x)
            if x:
                login(request, x)
                return redirect('/stock')
    context = {'form': forms}
    return render(request, "users/login.html", context)
```

and the log of my code is :

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 07, 2022 - 15:23:25
Django version 4.0.4, using settings 'Ngoci.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
moradi
moradi
r123456m123456
r123456m123456
None
```

Comment: Did you modify  `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in your `settings.py `?

Comment: did you run ``` manage migrate``` for the new model? Please add more Details

Comment: of cause he did it: otherwise he receive not implemented error, and he write authenticate return None, not exception.

Comment: @BernhardVallant no, i don't modify that, i only code these files step by step in addition admin account that create with createsuperuser command can log in only new users can`t login, all new users create from django admin

Comment: @Ayman yes i do, user stored in database, i can query over users and data of them, everything okay only thing is worng the user can not login

Comment: @MaximDanilov data comes from form is exactly same the data in database, why authenticate() function return none? username and password match with database, another question why superuser can login only new user can not??

Comment: print(x.password) says: you save wrong password for every new user in database. it should be something like: "pbkdf2_sha254$260000$CeVTLp974zBgm8Ld4SocP9$/RoXJ93/BrFxxjNS7U7Htyjjl6fGwDEnwuGX9WqLQbc="

Answer (score 0):

in your form you can use `forms.PasswordInput` instead of `TextInput`.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput

in your User model is better to use custom permissions (usermodel.branch_change, usermodel.finance_change etc.) instead of additional boolean fields (BranchManager, FinanceManager etc.)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions

for login is better to use LoginView from django.contrib.auth
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView

I don't know how you setup autorization in setup.py, but this is not your case.

I think you work wrong with passwords. Can you check how you save passwords in database? if you save user simply,

```
user(**user_form.clened_data).save()  # this is not works.
```

this is not works without `make_password`:

```
user(**(user_form.clened_data | {password=make_password(user_form.clened_data['password'])} )).save()
```

after that it should work.

as additional:
`authenticate` depends on methods:

```
UserModel.objects.get_by_natural_key(username)

user.check_password(password)

getattr(user, 'is_active', True)
```

You can check it in Django shell (`python manage.py shell`): if you don't receive a user from db, or other methods returns False - here is answer, why you can not authenticate by username and password.

Comment: at first i create new user from django admin panel, and no modify user registration method, superuser that create in first step of deploying django can login from this form, why new created user can not?

Comment: new created user is active?

Comment: yes user is active, in addition  have a superuser access

Comment: i add info in answer

Comment: i update the question for more info

Comment: your update tell, that you save a plain password without make_password  function: try to create SU-user with python manage.py createsuperuser and after that try to compare in database user(moradi) password and SU-user password. for SU you can see in password something like "pbkdf2_sha254$260000$CeVTLp974zBgm8Ld4SocP9$/RoXJ93/BrFxxjNS7U7Htyjjl6fGwDEnwuGX9WqLQbc="

Comment: yes, its true, but question is why after adding user app to my django app password for user that create in admin panel save as plain text??